# How does one change their Gmail account password in Windows 8 Mail?

Tags: windows-8, email, gmail

A friend recently changed their Gmail password via mail.google.com and needs to update that password in Windows 8 Mail.  However, there does not appear to be any way to do so that I've found thus far.  Google searches have only resulted in answers saying to uninstall and create new Windows accounts and then reinstall and other completely ridiculous steps. There are other accounts set up in Mail, and saved emails from past years that all need to be kept in tact.

In every other email client I've ever used in the history of the Internet, you can always go into the account setting and change the password there. What is MS Mail's convoluted method of making this very simple change?

Comment: Once Win8 Mail get know the password is changed it should ask the user for the new one. What happens for you instead? Is he still able to use the gmail account? any error message?

Comment: Exactly as Máté Juhász says: after the password has been changed via the web app, the Windows Mail app will complain that `The Gmail account settings are not up to date` and offer a button to `correct account`. The reason it works like this is that it uses OAuth and does not store your password: it lets you authenticate on Gmail and then stores the authentication token.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not happening. When we try to sync, no errors or windows of any kind appear.  It just says "Syncing" up at the top right corner and that's it.  Your input is helpful though, it gives me some ideas to try.